# Графики в delphi

Tags: delphi, график

Есть пара вопросов по возможности построения графиков в делфи, никак не могу найти, как сделать так, что б:

1. при наведении на график (на саму построенную линию) выводились значения точки, на которую ты навелся, не координаты около курсора, а "выделялись" значения с осей;
2. возможно ли сделать так, что б например щелкнув на точку графика её значения перенеслись, например, в лист бокс?

И как правильно все это будет называться?

Comment: ответ от BuilderC помог, хотя все равно есть вещи которые так и не работают как хотелось бы (не получается привязаться к линиям все равно все координаты выдаются везде где захочешь)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вполне для обеих Ваших задач подходят штатные `TChart` и `TSeries`.
Для первой: обработчик события `TChart OnMouseMove` вернет координаты курсора в окне `TChart`, а методы `TChart BottomAxis->CalcPosPoint(X)` и `LeftAxis->CalcPosPoint(Y)` вернут физические координаты графика. Таким образом можно помещать координаты, например, в одну из панелей статусного бара формы.

Для второй: сгодится событие `TSeries OnDblClick`, обработчик которого возвращает индекс точки на кривой. Конечно, тут желательно, чтобы кривая была из класса `TPointSeries` для удобства попадания мышью в точку, а не в промежность :-)

Comment: Извините, я применил си-шный синтаксис, а у Вас - Delphi. Ну, ничего, разберетсь.

Comment: @Bob, ничего не меняется. Просто, если точки на Ваших кривых стоят на значительном расстоянии друг от друга, то мышью на TLineSeries, где точки не видны, непросто попасть в цель. TPointSeries унаследован от TCustomSeries.

Comment: Используйте метод TSeries OnDblClick или OnClick. С "фигней" разберетесь сами, я полагаю. Можно щелкать и по изображениям кривых на Легенде.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте [TMS Advanced Charts](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/advchart.asp)

Comment: В нем все это возможно?

Comment: Да, нечто подобное